# Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '(Array<String!>, String)' in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, search, contains

I am trying to determine whether an `Array` contains a certain string value using `contains`. The array is defined like so:

```
var myArray: Array<String!> = []
```

This is in a separate file (as it is manipulated in a number of different places), to the one in which I am trying to do the following:

```
var searchString: String! = "Search"

if contains(myArray, searchString) {
     println("Exists")
}
else {
     println("Doesn't Exist")
}
```

Each time I try to run the above code, I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '(Array<String!>, String)'
```

I have tried the following:

```
if myArray.contains(searchString) {
...
```

But then I get a error saying:

```
'Array<String!>' does not have a member named contains
```

How do I use `contains` without Swift returning an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issues is with the type of `myArray`. Why do you need to use `String!`?

This works in Swift 1.2

```
var myArray: Array<String> = []

var searchString: String = "Search"

if contains(myArray, searchString) {
    println("Exists")
}
else {
    println("Doesn't Exist")
}
```

and this in Swift 2.0 (as of Xcode 7 Beta 3)

```
var myArray: Array<String> = []

var searchString: String = "Search"

if myArray.contains(searchString) {
    print("Exists")
}
else {
    print("Doesn't Exist")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the implicit optional type `Array<String!>`. Remove the exclamation mark and the code compiles fine.
Do you really need an optional type? In many cases you could use an empty string as "no string" value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two variants of the `contains()` function:

```
// 1
func contains<S : SequenceType, L : BooleanType>(seq: S, predicate: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> L) -> Bool
// 2
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

Your code calls the second one, which requires that the sequence 
elements conform to the `Equatable` protocol. This is the case for
`String`, but not for the (implicitly unwrapped optional) `String!`.

Replacing `String` by `String!` would solve the problem:

```
var myArray: Array<String> = []
```

If that is not possible then you can use the first variant of
`contains()` which uses a *predicate* as the second argument:

```
// Swift 1.2:
if contains(myArray, { $0 == searchString } ) { ... }

// Swift 2:
if myArray.contains( { $0 == searchString } ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a string array in swift should not be generic in this case, that would work for you

```
var myArray: [String] = []

var searchString: String! = "Search"

if contains(myArray, searchString) {
     println("Exists")
}
else {
     println("Doesn't Exist")
}
```